# Get AttributeError after upgrading to IPython13

Tags: python, ipython

I upgraded my `IPython` installation with `pip`, and when I use `ipython`, it failed like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Shell'
```

But when I try `$(which ipython)`, it starts up normally.

What may be the reason of that `AttributeError`?

Answer (score 0):

Look under ~/.ipython. There's probably a configuration script there that is using the old API.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that an `alias` in `.bashrc` overrode `ipython` in `$PATH`, and it was set to be an old version of ipython